# download attachments from yahoo mail api

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-mail

How should I **construct and combine the oauth token to download the attachment** from [Yahoo Mail API](http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/docs/user_guide/DownloadAttachment.html#)?  Any java example or link will be a great help.

For other command like List Messages, I can construct as JSON though.

```
{
  "method": "ListMessages",
  "params":
  [
    {
      "fid": "Inbox",
      "startMid": 0,
      "numMid": 10,
      "startInfo": 0,
      "numInfo": 1
    }
  ],
  "id": 1234567890
}
```